# Change the case of specific letters in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to change the following string

`fgsloiwrthowmwohitjwptpbspdfmjlsihjwslihj`

to this string

`FGsloIwrtHowMwoHItJwpTpBspDfmJlsIhJwslIHJ`

I want to capitalize letters A through J and leave the rest alone using regular expressions.

Something like `[a-j]` to `[A-J]`.

Comment: Does it have to use a regular expression, or are you just looking for a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
    $lower = range('a', 'j');
    $upper = range('A', 'J');
    echo str_replace($lower, $upper, 'fgsloiwrthowmwohitjwptpbspdfmjlsihjwslihj');
?>
```

See [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

http://codepad.viper-7.com/I8dV8N

Answer (score 5):

```
$old = array('a', 'b', .... , 'j');
$new = array('A', 'B', .... , 'J');

$fixed = str_replace($old, $new, $your_string_here);
```

Comment: or you can look into `preg_replace`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a regular expression, consider using [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback).

**Example:**

```
$string = 'fgsloiwrthowmwohitjwptpbspdfmjlsihjwslihj';
$string = preg_replace_callback('/[a-j]/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'), $string);

var_dump($string);
```

**Outputs:**

```
string(41) "FGsloIwrtHowmwoHItJwptpBspDFmJlsIHJwslIHJ"
```